# Script Light(Spot) for Multiple Objects

Tags: light

- I'm using this script.
- Always(...) + Python (Script) = Nothing...
- Do I need to configure anything else?
- List item
- The script does not work.

  ```
  import bpy

  scene = bpy.context.scene
  lamp = bpy.data.lamps['Lamp']
  lamp.energy = 10000
  lamp.type = 'SPOT'
  lamp.distance = 250000
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script creating what you want:

```
import bpy
C = bpy.context
scene = C.scene
bpy.ops.object.lamp_add(type='SPOT')
C.selected_objects[0].name = 'Lamp'
lamp = bpy.data.lamps['Lamp']
lamp.energy = 20000
lamp.distance = 250000
```